# Everytime I create a View using Views Drupal times out

Tags: views

So if I create a view with more than 2 fields Drupals gets really slow and timesout. I am pretty much stuck here.

My content never shows. Anyone seen this behavior? This is a completely custom theme and I am very new.

I am using Views with Drupal 7.

Comment: Look at the error log (apache), what is the error message? Max exec time or memory limit? Increase the problematic one..

Comment: It would be helpful to have more info on the machine and environment you are running it in. Basic info such as Operating system and a dump of your php.ini would be very helpful.